# Prevent specific URL in Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In Apache's .htaccess, how do I block a specific URL? It may or may not have parameters.

http://www.my_domain.com/avoid_this_str/?some_param=some_number

Maybe have it send back a nice error code?

(I always feel unsure about writing those rules!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /avoid_this_str/\?.+=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This will return forbidden 403 error for http://www.my_domain.com/avoid_this_str/?some_param=some_number

To block  the url  without perameters, try

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /avoid_this_str/\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```